# How can I return a React.Component class from a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have read this post: [How can I return a class from a TypeScript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314114/how-can-i-return-a-class-from-a-typescript-function)

In the post linked above, this working code is displayed as an answer:

```
export class Foo {} // Foo is exported
export let factory = () : Foo => { // it could be return type of export function
    return Foo
};
```

The code I currently have is like so:

```
export class SimpleElement extends React.Component<any, any> {}
export let test = (): SimpleElement => {
  return SimpleElement;
};
```

And it gives the error:

`[ts]
Type 'typeof SimpleElement' is not assignable to type 'SimpleElement'.
  Property 'setState' is missing in type 'typeof SimpleElement'.`

I have looked into the setState error here ([Reactj, typescript Property 'setState' is missing in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568789/reactj-typescript-property-setstate-is-missing-in-type?rq=1)), but the answer doesn't seem particularly helpful for this.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're returning the class, not an instance of it (but you say that you will return an instance with `: SimpleElement`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055623/4808079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  Use typeof.

```
export class SimpleElement extends React.Component<any, any> {}
export let test = (): typeof SimpleElement => {
  return SimpleElement;
};
```