# Trying to get state into a const React class - always get TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, I'm new to React and asked a similar question earlier, but changed the form of my code. I am trying to get a state value in a const react class.

Here in my Article.js

```
  function changeClassName(childData) {
      console.log("GETS HERE!");
this.setState({
  dynamicClassName: childData
});
```

}

```
const Articles = ({ data, isLoading, error }) => {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(isLoading);
  const article_wrapper = data.nodes || [];

  if (error) {
    return <p>{error.message}</p>;
  }

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading ...</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="article">
      {article_wrapper.map( article =>
        <div key={article.node.nid} className="article-main-display">
       <h1 className="title" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(article.node.title)}/>
          <div className="img-div"><img src={article.node.field_image.src} /></div>

          <ControlForm parentMethod={changeClassName} />

          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(article.node.field_user_hsk_level)} />;
          <div className="field-name-field-chinese">
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(article.node.chinese)} />;
                  </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here in my ControlForm.js

Part of the render:

```
        <div className="form-item form-type-select form-group">
          <label className="control-label">Font Size</label>
          <select
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleSizeSelect}
            id="font-size"
            className="form-control form-select"
          >
            <option value="0">Small</option>
            <option value="1">Normal</option>
            <option value="2">Large</option>
            <option value="3">XL</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

And the class initiation looks like this:

```
class ControlForm extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { toggleActive: false, sizeSelect: "0", speed: 1.3, volume: .6};
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
    this.handleSpeedChange = this.handleSpeedChange.bind(this);
    this.handleVolumeChange = this.handleVolumeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSizeSelect = this.handleSizeSelect.bind(this);
  }
```

When I try to use this, I get this error:

```
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

However, anytime I try to convert `const Articles = ...` into a formal class X extends Component structure, I get a bunch of other errors.

How can I get state into this component successfully? I have been banging my head against a wall all day and I can't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: I can't see the part of your code using `this.setState`

Comment: In your Article component's constructor, try adding `this.changeClassName.bind(this)`

Comment: *I get a bunch of other errors* - fix them one by one then, you need to start somewhere. Since you're not using `parentMethod` and `dynamicClassName` anywhere, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve. Should the state be changed in Articles or ControlForm ?

Comment: I am trying to pass a value from ControlForm into this Articles const. That's literally all I want to do. I was following some other guide that had parentMethod and dynamicClassName, but I really have zero clue what I'm doing here. I don't feel like it should be this difficult to pass a value.

Comment: But ultimately, ALL I want to do, is click a button in ControlForm, and pass it to Article here. That's IT.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `const` then your file should be of `.ts` extension. To access the state in `.ts`, you need to define the type of the state in it. Please refer to this example of how you can do that:

[[Reactj, typescript Property 'setState' is missing in type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568789/reactj-typescript-property-setstate-is-missing-in-type][1])

Otherwise, if you want to work with `.jsx` then I would suggest you drop the const and declare the state outside the constructor.

Comment: I'm not married to using const. I am basing this on an example I saw that worked.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your **Articles** is not a React Component, that's why you cannot use setState function, then your function **changeClassName**
isn't declared in the React.Component, that's why you see this.setState is not a function. try this:

```
class Article extends React.Component {

 changeClassName = () => {
   //function body
 }
 //your codes...
}
```

if you seeing this.setState is not a function, most of the time it just because you do not bind your function. when declaring your function in React class, try just using es6 arrow function like:

```
yourFunction = (args) => {
   this.setState({
    //.....
   });
 }
```

then you do not need mannualy bind your function in constuctor anymore

Comment: When I change const Articles = ({ data, isLoading, error }) => { to class Article extends React.Component {, I get "Syntax error: Unexpected token (67:11)"

Comment: @AndrewAlexander can you share your updated code? Syntax error is because there is a typo in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem begins with this whole block of code:

```
  function changeClassName(childData) {
      console.log("GETS HERE!");
this.setState({
  dynamicClassName: childData
});
```

Is this a React component? If so, is a functional component or a class based component?

What I am getting at is that you need to create a class-based React component like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Now, you will notice, once you have a class-based React component, you must include a `render()` method or else you will get an error. What you return inside of it is project specific.

You also need to create a class-based component so you can initialize state like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { images: [] };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In this case I have set an initial state inside my `App` component of images to be an empty array.

Then only within that class can you update your state via `this.setState({ images: response.data.results });` for example.